# iOS 11 - Offload app feature - Push Notifications

Tags: ios, ipad, push-notification, ios11

How to does push notifications work in case of "Offload app" feature in iPad?

I am facing an issue in iOS 11 on iPad, my application still receives push notifications in "Offload app" status. Is there any delegate or a notification the app can handle in this state.

So far i couldn't find any documentation for the same. 
Suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I didn't expect. I just god a notification message for Facebook, but the application is in offload mode.
I event can't find that app in settings, for example, to change the notification settings. And it makes sense - that app is not exist on my phone (because it was offloaded (that was my assumption))....
BTW, I have iOS 11.2.5